# Enable to generate pdf (It give me plan html text in a file) - dompdf

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, dompdf

```
$content['profile_data'] = file_get_contents(base64_decode($profile_data,true));
$pdf = PDF::loadHtml(htmlentities($content['profile_data']));
$pdf->setOptions(['setIsHtml5ParserEnabled'=>true]);
// $pdf->setPaper('A4','landscape');
$pdf->stream();
$pdf->save($path . '/' . $file_name.'.pdf');
```

The whole code seems ok. The html coming from a url. I am trying to save it in a file as pdf.

But it gives me a plan Text HTML when i try to open. Please help me

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not render (`->render()`).

Short example:

```
$html = ''; // Your html.
$size = 'A4';
$orientation = 'portrait';
$options = new Options(
    [
        'isHtml5ParserEnabled'    => true, // little faster
    ]
);
$domPdf = new Dompdf($options);
$domPdf->loadHtml($html);
$domPdf->setPaper($size, $orientation);
$domPdf->render();
$pdf = $domPdf->output();
```

---

And here i post all that i do with dompdf -
i searched a lot, lots of learn by doing ... perhaps it helps:

*Following is for version `v0.8.6`*

```
/**
 * Returns pdf from html.
 *
 * @param string $html
 * @param string $size
 * @param string $orientation
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function htmlToPdf($html, $size = 'A4', $orientation = 'portrait')
{
    $options = new Options(
        [
            //'logOutputFile'           => 'data/log.htm',
            'isPhpEnabled'            => false,
            'isRemoteEnabled'         => false,
            'isJavascriptEnabled'     => false,
            'isHtml5ParserEnabled'    => true, // little faster
            'isFontSubsettingEnabled' => false,
            'debugPng'                => false,
            'debugKeepTemp'           => false,
            'debugCss'                => false,
            'debugLayout'             => false,
            'debugLayoutLines'        => false,
            'debugLayoutBlocks'       => false,
            'debugLayoutInline'       => false,
            'debugLayoutPaddingBox'   => false,
            //'pdfBackend'              => 'CPDF',
        ]
    );
    $domPdf = new Dompdf($options);
    $domPdf->loadHtml($this->minimizeHtml($html));
    $domPdf->setPaper($size, $orientation);
    $domPdf->render();
    return $domPdf->output();
}

/**
 * Minimizes the html source.
 *
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6225706/3411766
 *
 * @param string $html
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function minimizeHtml($html)
{
    return preg_replace(
        [
            '/\>[^\S ]+/s',  // strip whitespaces after tags, except space
            '/[^\S ]+\</s',  // strip whitespaces before tags, except space
            '/(\s)+/s'       // shorten multiple whitespace sequences
        ],
        [
            '>',
            '<',
            '\\1'
        ],
        $html
    );
}
```

Comment: You are right @cotton but here is the issue. Here is my html [https://www2.pcrecruiter.net/pcrbin/reg7.aspx?reference=fGRhbmFrb3dlbmFzc29jaWF0ZXMurZMNyAGR3df0ctxJKcDjW7dogF4FIKDXz24E9PbeNrGzWRcDJ4mFDQEwwE0BPrsW%2BeRkqaHPuc31Mxv170EvHNxYIg6ALzGNIkYeiZP%2BiEgGF16VRJv9WcRkq%2F3uBQaAXL2U6e3HB%2BmQdACzAuYa9y4P5EbDl72SQtGuG0O%2F9%2F%2BVuAYPIrMYIpeoGfuXom8ckEkSsCrt5jV6A7nk2XA%3D]

I want this to be stored as file.
when i use your code im getting this error 
Frame not found in cellmap
Please help i researched alot nothing found. The link html i cant change anything in it.

Comment: If I do  `htmlentities(file_get_contents($url_above,true));`
It stores but give me a plain html as text in pdf file. I dont know how to generate it properly. Please help

Comment: `$content['profile_data'] = htmlentities(file_get_contents(base64_decode($profile_data,true)));
                    $html = $content['profile_data'];
                    $options = new Options(
                        ['isHtml5ParserEnabled'    => true, // little faster]);
                    $domPdf = new Dompdf($options);
                    $domPdf->loadHtml($html);
                    $domPdf->setPaper($size, $orientation);
                    $domPdf->render();
                    $pdf = $domPdf->output();  file_put_contents($path . '/' . $file_name.'.pdf', $pdf);`

Comment: If you use `htmlentities` on HTML then i do not know if dompdf can handle it.
I also do not know i why you load external HTML. Could be a security risk. At least you could disable JS and PHP in dompdf (`isJavascriptEnabled` and `isPhpEnabled` to false), if possible.

Comment: I understand, But actually, I need to create a pdf of the data i have in PCR. PCR give me basecode and after decoding it gives me a link. so Then i have to use that link to make pDF. This is where i am stuck :|

Comment: I dont know what PCR is. If you think the HTML is no security risk then remove the `htmlentities`. I just tried it on my side: dompdf does print HTML (`<div> ....`) instead of creating a pdf using HTML if you add `htmlentities`.

Comment: how? Can you send me your code please... Because when i remove the htmlentities it gives me error `Frame not found in cellmap`

Comment: @QaisarMughal I used the code i posted above. The error seems to be another problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34830469/solution-for-frame-not-found-in-cellmap `I had a similar problem, but was able to discover that I had an extra < in one of my text`

Comment: Thanks for all help I have resolved it via https://mpdf.github.io/
this is a good option too Thanks

Comment: @QaisarMughal Good. Just wondering: does mpdf accept the HTML encoded with `htmlentities`, or did you remove it? If you removed `htmlentities` then mpdf may "correct" the HTML. Would still suggest to look what was wrong with the HTML you received.

Comment: Actually I removed htmlentities. I dont know what going on in backend. But so far it works fine and little slow. But im still hoping someone can fix for the DOMPDF.

Comment: As i read not dompdf caused the problem. The HTML should have "broken" tags (as the ppl posted on the link i added). Example: `<div my text</div>` (missing `>`) or `<p>my number < 2 ... </p>` (broken due to unmasked `<` in cell text). But you alone have the source HTML =)